# Return a value from a WebMethod based on conditions provided in the WebMethod

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

I have a jQuery Ajax WebMethod call as shown below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnsubmit").click(function () {

            var arr = new Array();
            arr.push($("#control1").val()); arr.push($("#control2").val()); arr.push($("#control13 option:selected").val()); arr.push($("#control4 option:selected").val()); arr.push($("#control15 option:selected").val());

            var requestedData = JSON.stringify(arr);
            requestedData = "{'details':'" + requestedData + "'}";

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "EmployeeDemotion.aspx/Save",
                data: requestedData,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                  //check the value returned from the WebMethod and provide alerts accordingly

                },

                error: function (result) {
                    alert("Error");
                }

            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

and, the WebMethod is as below:

```
 [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
     public static InsertDetails[] Save(string details)
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable(); DataTable dts = new DataTable();

            List<InsertDetails> data = new List<InsertDetails>();
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string[] Tags = js.Deserialize<string[]>(details);
            object[] obj = new object[8];
            obj[0] = Tags[0].ToString(); obj[1] = Tags[1].ToString(); obj[2] = Tags[2].ToString(); obj[3] = Tags[3].ToString();
            obj[4] = Tags[4].ToString(); 


            int a = //say condition 1
            int b = //say condition 2
            if (a< b)
            {

             //insert into database and set a value which says the insertion has succeeded

            }
            else
            {
                //alert that data cannot be inserted
            }

            return data.ToArray();
        }
```

Now I require a value of any possible type (boolean,array,string,integer or other) to be returned to the ajax method so that the success function in the ajax method alerts the status of insertion (as commented in te snippet) i.e; a value should be returned along with the last statement "return data.ToArray();" to the ajax method.
I do not require the  element 'data' to be returned, the value which validates the insertion should be returned either along with 'data' or in any other form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

not sure what you want. Whether you want both the data and the flag to be returned to the client function or simply the flag.

- Case 1 : all that you want is to return a message about the action that took place inside `save`

  just change your save method like this

  ```
  [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
  public static string Save(string details)
  {
        string message =string.Empty;

        /// rest of the usual code of yours   
        ///
        if (a< b)
        {
           //rest of the code
           message = "Insertion Successful";
        }
        else
        {
           //rest of the code
           message = "Error Occured";
        }
  }
  ```

  and in your client side inside the ajax `success`, simple do this:

  ```
  success: function (result) {
                 alert(result.d);
  }
  ```
- Case 2: you want to send data also in case insertion is successful

  make a wrapper and append the data and the flag both to it. Serialize it and
  then send it to the client side function. i.e

  ```
  //wrapper class
  public class ServiceResponse
  {
     public bool IsSuccess {get;set;}
     public string Message {get;set;}
  }
  ```

  now inside your `save` do this:

  ```
  [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
  public static string Save(string details)
  {
        ServiceResponse serviceResponse =new ServiceResponse();

        /// rest of the usual code of yours   
        ///
        if (a< b)
        {
           //rest of the code
            serviceResponse.IsSuccess= true;
            serviceResponse.Message = String.Join(",",data.ToArray());
        }
        else
        {
           //rest of the code
           serviceResponse.IsSuccess = false;
        }

      return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(serviceResponse);
  }
  ```

  and use it inside your client method like :

  ```
    success: function (result) {
            var jsonData = $.parseJSON(result.d);
            if(jsonData.IsSuccess){
                alert('success');
                grid.data(jsonData.Message);
            }
            else{
                alert('failure');
            } 
    }
  ```